# Cannot get value of parameter passed as query string in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I want to use query string in one of my page in Codeigniter i have made changes to  following settings:

> 1- Change to $config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
>
> 2- Change to permitted_uri_chars $config['permitted_uri_chars'] =
>   'a-z 0-9~%.:_-?';
>
> 3- $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
>       $config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';    $config['function_trigger']       => 'm'; $config['directory_trigger']    =
>   'd';

```
Class Test extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
$this->load->helper('url');
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$_GET);
}

public function shoes() {

echo $_GET['size']

}
}
```

> Notice:
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: size
>
> Filename: controllers/test.php
>
> Line Number: 40

Problem is i cannot get the value of parameter size in controller method. Please help to sort out my issue.

Comment: Actually i am trying it on localhost this is my url : http://localhost/M_server/c=test&m=shoes?size=42

Comment: You have ? before size should be & the ? should be `localhost/M_server/?c=test&m=shoes&size=42`

Comment: And change this `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';` to `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 : http://localhost/M_server/?c=test&m=shoes&size=43 is working but the other controllers which work on segment are not working and giving the following message : The localhost page isn’t working localhost redirected you too many times.

Comment: And you then should be able to use `$this->input->get('size')`

Comment: yes it is working but i think other controllers  localhost/M_server/home is not working and following messages are shown up :  The localhost page isn’t working localhost redirected you too many times.

Comment: Try `http://localhost/M_server/?c=home` or in `anchor(c=home, 'home')` you may need to add ? `anchor(?c=home, 'home')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109317/discussion-between-user3653474-and-wolfgang1983).